# Web Design - Flash AS3 - button bug

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I've run into this problem twice in all the site's I've designed and I can't figure out how to fix it. (The flash compiler has not given me any errors for this.)

Here is the link first of all
http://rollingsquare.com/AKJ/akj.html

Once you're in the site click on portfolio and then click on "the excelsior" what happens is that for the first 4-5 clicks it won't do what it's supposed to do and it'll start randomly either stopping at a frame or playing a from a frame. Once it's done it's randomness it all works perfect again, but those initial clicks do not take you anywhere.

This is an externally loaded SWF and I've loaded it with 2 different techniques hoping it was that but that didn't fix it.

I've tried simply placing a UiLoader and linking it and what it is now, a var myLoader.

Anyone run into something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to be more specific in asking programming questions. I almost took it as a spam link.

Anyway's if I am getting you correct, the initial thumbnail clicks don't load the image.You should probably use individual loader for each of those large images.

Comment: Hey thank you for responsding i'll make sure to be more specific next time. The problem is not the really not the loader but to gotoandstop function. I have each one of the project links on the left gotoandstop on a frame label but that code doesn't want to kick in. It works perfectly on every other page of the site but not on this page. Would you know why?